# Random numbers with one answer

Tags: delphi, random, numbers, delphi-7

I have this code

```
label1.Caption:= 'Number is:' + inttostr(random(2) + 1);
```

but in result I have "1" every time. Can you explain what I did wrong?

Comment: You're lucky! But anyway, don't forget to initialize random seed by calling `Randomize` somewhere when the application starts.

Comment: Please can you supply a complete program for which Random(2) returns 1 on every call. Until you do that there is no question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To initialize the random number generator you must call [`Randomize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Randomize) method before to use the random function.